# No "datesdisabled" in updateDateInput in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I built an app in R Shiny which uses time series data that excludes many dates. Within the app a user can select a new dataset, so the dates available will change. I'm using `updateDateInput` to update the `dateInput` selector. However, `updateDateInput` does not seem to allow the `datesdisabled` function?

Here is a reprex:

```
library(shiny)

# Sample 3 dates and disable the rest
 
my_dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-31'), by = "day"), 3)    
date_choices <- seq.Date(from = min(my_dates), to = max(my_dates), by = 1)
dates_disabled <- date_choices[!(date_choices %in% my_dates)]

ui <- fluidPage(
    dateInput("date", "Select Date",
              min = min(date_choices),
              max = max(date_choices),
              value = max(date_choices),
              datesdisabled = dates_disabled),
    actionButton("click", "Click Me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$click, {
        my_dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-31'), by = "day"), 3)
        date_choices <- seq.Date(from = min(my_dates), to = max(my_dates), by = 1)
        dates_disabled <- date_choices[!(date_choices %in% my_dates)]
        updateDateInput(
            session, 
            "date",
            min = min(date_choices),
            max = max(date_choices),
            value = max(date_choices),
            datesdisabled = dates_disabled)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the button is clicked and the `updateDateInput` runs, I get this error:

> Warning: Error in updateDateInput: unused argument (datesdisabled =
> dates_disabled)

I guess there is the option of changing the date to a character and using `selectInput`? But then I don't get the nice calendar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the `datesdisabled` argument is not available in the update function. You can change the disabled dates by moving the UI declaration into the server and feed it to the client with `renderUI()`.

The sample does not declare the date input in the UI but a `uiOutput("date")`. The server can dynamically create the `dateInput` using the `datesdisabled` argument. This way you can change the disabled dates.

The example will pick only 3 enabled dates after every button click.

```
# Reprex: The actual implementation of this uses data from a file:
#    1. Reads data file before ui and server are established
#    2. Does a bunch of calculations
#    3. Identifies dates that exist in data file
#    4. The data file is getting updated in the background from another application.
#    5. Allows user to click the button to update the data file. Reprex shows code
#       that is used to update the date selector based on new data read. Dates are 
#       random in reprex, but would come from data file in actual code.

# Sample 3 dates and disable the rest - actual code reads data file here
#   and parses out dates that exist in records

my_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-31'), by = "day")
date_choices <- sample(my_dates, 31-3)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("date"), textOutput("disabled"),
    actionButton("click", "Click Me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    dates_disabled <- reactiveVal(NULL)
    
    # Init 'dates_disabled()' once before Shiny flushes the reactive system with callback,
    #   using date_choices that exist in original data set

    onFlush(fun = function () {dates_disabled(date_choices)}, once = TRUE)
    
    # dateInput widget
    output$date <- renderUI({
        maxDate <- as.Date(max(setdiff(my_dates, dates_disabled())),
                           origin = "1970-01-01")
        dateInput(input = "date", 
                  label = "Select Date",
                  min = min(my_dates),
                  max = max(my_dates),
                  value = maxDate,
                  datesdisabled = dates_disabled())
    })
    
    # This output makes it easier to test if it works by showing the enabled dates
    output$disabled <- renderPrint({
        req(dates_disabled()) # only run this when 'dates_disabled' is initialized properly
        Enabled <- as.Date(setdiff(seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-31'), by = "day"), 
                                   dates_disabled()), 
                           origin = '1970-01-01')
        paste("Enabled:", paste(Enabled[order(Enabled)], collapse = ", "))
    })
    
    # Set new datesdisabled on button click
    #    Actual code would read updated data file and parse new dates
    observeEvent(input$click, {
        SelectedDates <- sample(my_dates, 31-3)
        dates_disabled( SelectedDates )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is very close. Thanks you! However, when the app is initialized, all of the dates are available instead of just the 3 "original" dates. I need the `datesdisabled` to run when loading the app. Note that the button click in the new app actually loads a new dataframe, so I don't want to simulate a button click in the server.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is:  Is there a way to call `renderUI` once when the app runs, without clicking the button or simulating a button click?

Comment: If the data comes from a file a `reactiveFileReader` might be interesting. But only when the file does not only initialize the `dates_disabled()`. In my sample I used a way to initialize it with using an `onFlush` callback. With `once = TRUE` it will be run the first time enabling the 1st, 15th. and 31st of January.

Comment: Of course, you can force the `renderUI` by changing any reactive expression that it uses. In my sample any change in `dates_disabled` makes sure that the UI is rendered again.

Comment: I made changes: (1) input$date shows in the output box (otherwise the user is confused), and (2) changed `onFlush` so the initial date choices are from what exists in the file when the app is run. I considered `reactiveFileReader` but (1) I would still have the issue of updating the calendar dates with `datesdisabled`, and (2) the app is heavy in calculations so runs kind of slow, and I don't want to add any additional lag time (the user will likely only click the button to update the data once or twice per session).

Comment: I did an edit to the code (as mentioned above) and will accept the answer after the edit is accepted. Thank you, this helps a lot!