# Adjust output for dates in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The APP below is working normally. However, I would like the output values in relation to the dates to be different, that is, instead of coming out 2021-01-01 I would like them to come out like this: 01-01-2021. Obviously, without changing the `df database` directly and yes on the output.

Thank you very much!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df,date, d1,d2){
  
  df <- structure(
   list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
         d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}    
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                     sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       selectInput("date", label = h4("Date"),""),
                                       selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                       selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                       br(),
                                       actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "date",labe ="Date", unique(data()$date))
    updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data()$d1))
    updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data()$d2))
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**#NEW CODE**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(openxlsx)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(openxlsx)
library(writexl)
library(readxl)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   fileInput("file", "Please upload a file", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       selectInput("date", label = h4("Date"),""),
                                       selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                       selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel( 
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df1 <- reactiveValues(dat=NULL)
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
    df
  })
  
  observe({
    df1$dat <- data()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    
    if (!is.null(df1$dat)) {
      data <- df1$dat
      updateSelectInput(session, "date", label = "Date", unique(data$Date))
      updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data$D1))
      updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data$D2))
    }
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `dateInput()` [input type](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/dateInput.html), instead of `selectInput()`?

If you only want particular dates to be eligible for selection, you can disable other dates within `dateInput()`. However, this becomes [slightly more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943772/no-datesdisabled-in-updatedateinput-in-r-shiny), as you aren't able to update the `datesdisabled` argument with the `updateDateInput()` function, isabled I am assuming you are wanting US style `day-month-year` format, but if not, you can edit the format.

For example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df,date, d1,d2){
    df <- structure(
        list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
             d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}    
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                            br(),
                            
                            tabPanel("",
                                     sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                             
                                             uiOutput("date"),
                                             selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                             selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                             br(),
                                             actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                                         ),
                                         
                                         mainPanel(
                                         ))
                            )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
    data <- reactive(function.cl())
      
    output$date <- renderUI({
        all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
        disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
        
        dateInput(input = "date", 
                  label = "Select Date",
                  min = min(data()$date),
                  max = max(data()$date),
                  value = max(data()$date),
                  format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                  datesdisabled = disabled)
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data()$d1))
        updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data()$d2))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit:** Alternatively, you have just defined the dates above as strings, so you can just reformat the strings.

I.e. the function where you define your data can just be changed:

```r
function.cl<-function(df,date, d1,d2){
    
    df <- structure(
        list(date = c("01-01-2021","01-02-2021","01-03-2021","01-04-2021","01-05-2021"),
             d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}
```

If you really want to use the `selectInput()` function *and* you really want the dates as `Date` types rather than characters, you could also just format back and forth between strings and dates.

For example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df,date, d1,d2){
    
    df <- structure(
        list(date = as.Date(c("01-01-2021","01-02-2021","01-03-2021","01-03-2021","01-05-2021"), format = "%m-%d-%Y"),
             d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}    
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                            br(),
                            
                            tabPanel("",
                                     sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                             
                                             selectInput("date", label = h4("Date"),""),
                                             selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                             selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                             br(),
                                             actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
                                         ),
                                         
                                         mainPanel(
                                         ))
                            )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
    data <- reactive(function.cl())
    
    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, "date",labe ="Date", unique(format(data()$date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")))
        updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data()$d1))
        updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data()$d2))
    })    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I liked this first way you did it, using dateInput(). It got better. But I would like some help with this new form you provided. I have a case where the database is being inserted by fileInput and I am not setting the df in the code. I'm going to put this new code which is similar above for you to see. I would just like your help regarding how it would look in this code using dateInput().

Comment: Why don't you mark this as accepted then, and/or upvote and post a new question with your new problem. If you link it here after you post it, I will see if I can answer if for you

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience. I asked a new question, if you can take a look I would appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706475/change-the-selectinput-to-a-dateinput-in-shiny

Comment: No problem at all. I'll have a look at your other question when I get a minute :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had updated your code above. I will update my answer, and answer in the other question as well, just for clarity :)

Comment: Hi Sam Rogers! Could you take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807752/how-do-i-insert-days-that-are-holidays-into-a-shiny-app    Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, having a look now

Comment: Hi Sam Rogers! Sorry to ask you to see another question. But I remembered that I saw on your profile that you are a statistician and a programmer so I think you can help. My brother Antonio asked the question, we are working on the problem together. If you can take a look, I appreciate it. Any help is appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840372/forecasting-analysis-in-r