# Change the selectInput to a dateInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I made an app that is triggered when I use a database by fileInput. The database is this `df` that I inserted below, but it is in excel format. This base that is in excel I insert in fileInput.

```
df <- structure(
   list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
         d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}
```

However, would I like to change the `selectInput()` that refers dates to a `dateInput()`? Also, I would like the dates to be presented in day-month-year style.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(openxlsx)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(openxlsx)
library(writexl)
library(readxl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   fileInput("file", "Please upload a file", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       selectInput("date", label = h4("Date"),""),
                                       selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                       selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel( 
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df1 <- reactiveValues(dat=NULL)
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
    df
  })
  
  observe({
    df1$dat <- data()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    
    if (!is.null(df1$dat)) {
      data <- df1$dat
      updateSelectInput(session, "date", label = "Date", unique(data$Date))
      updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data$D1))
      updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data$D2))
    }
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68705569/1858667), this is fairly straight-forward as long as your input file is consistently named and arranged (though this shouldn't be assumed, and you would be wise to check this on input of a data set - do this in the `else` statement of the data `eventReactive()`).

Assuming you also want only the values that are present in your data set to be available, here is the full code edited from my answer to your other question that should enable you to use the `dateInput()` input type with arbitrary dates from the input file.

The other thing to notice is that because the UI component is generated in the server *after* the data is uploaded, there would normally not be a date picker field, because it has not been generated yet. So I have added a dummy date picker field which will update when someone uploads a file. This is mainly just for UI consistency, so that it doesn't suddenly appear when someone uploads a file, and is otherwise not there.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(openxlsx)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(openxlsx)
library(writexl)
library(readxl)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                            br(),
                            
                            tabPanel("",
                                     fileInput("file", "Please upload a file", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                     sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                             
                                             uiOutput("date"),
                                             selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                             selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                             br(),
                                             
                                         ),
                                         
                                         mainPanel( 
                                         ))
                            )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
        if (is.null(input$file)) {
            return(NULL)
        }
        else {
            df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
            return(df)
        }
    })
    
    output$date <- renderUI({
        if (!is.null(input$file)) {
            
            all_dates <- seq(as.Date(min(data()$date)), as.Date(max(data()$date)), by = "day")
            disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
            
            dateInput(input = "date", 
                      label = "Select Date",
                      min = min(data()$date),
                      max = max(data()$date),
                      value = max(data()$date),
                      format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                      datesdisabled = disabled)
        }
        else {
            dateInput(input = "date", 
                      label = "Select Date",
                      min = min("1970-01-01"),
                      max = max(Sys.Date()),
                      format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
        }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$file, {
        
        req(data)
        data <- data()
        data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
        print(data)
        updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data$d1))
        updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data$d2))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks again Sam! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `selectInput` code for date to `dateInput`

```
dateInput("date", label = h4("Date"),"", format = 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
```

and in `observeEvent` change `updateSelectInput` to `updateDateInput`

```
updateDateInput(session, "date", label = "Date", min = min(data$date), max = max(data$date))
```

Note that `data$date` should be of class `Date`, run `data$date <- as.Date(data$date)` to do that.

---

For testing I wrote the data shared to an excel file called `file.xlsx` using `writexl::write_xlsx(df, 'file.xlsx')`.

Complete app code -

```
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   fileInput("file", "Please upload a file", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       dateInput("date", label = h4("Date"),"", format = 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                                       selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                       selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel( 
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data1 <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
    df
  })

  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    
      req(data1)
      data <- data1()
      data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
      updateDateInput(session, "date", label = "Date", min = min(data$date), max = max(data$date))
      updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data$d1))
      updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data$d2))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I made adjustments as suggested. But I didn't quite understand this part ``data$date <- as.Date(data$date)``

Where do I make this adjustment? Could you show in the code?

Thank you again!

Comment: Basically, the date column should be of Date class. You can include it after `data <- df1$dat` and before `updateDateInput` in `observeEvent`.

Comment: @Jose I have included the complete code for the app.

Comment: Thanks Ronak for the suggestion you provided, but it still didn't work out very well for my case, anyway I really appreciate your help! :)